# Wordpress Woocommerce: Add custom condition in product query based on custom filter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a woocommerce project with little bit knowledge on wordpress. Now, I have got a requirement which is shared below:

```
1. Show date calendar on product listing page top of list not in sidebar. I am saving product availiblity based on date ranges in separate table. This table has product id, date start and date end.
2. Show sizes dropdown on product listing on top of list. Sizes filter is already showing in sidebard but client wants it on top. So, I wil disable it in sidebar.
3. When customer will select date and size, product list should be filter accordingly.
```

I have read wordpress documentation where wc_query has option to use either "EXISTS or NOT Exists" through ws_meta_query. But I am not able to understand, how can I put filter on product query using either "EXISTS or NOT EXISTS" with my custom raw query?

Can someone please guide me how can I implement whole requirement along with how can I EXISTS using raw sql query with product query?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

For first 2 points, you'll need [woocommerce_before_shop_loop](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_before_shop_loop) action to display your custom filters.

and for 3rd point, you'll need [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) action to control your queries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my query is how can I use my custom sql raw queries using "Exists" clause with product query?

Comment: You can't SQL raw queries with `pre_get_posts` you'll have to use `meta_query` and `tax_query` based on your data setup. You can spend some time learning how to use those things and you can also search for "Modify WooCommerce product query" there will be many articles on this topic. you can find an article here https://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-modifying-product-query/